# Draggable/Droppable for Battleship game

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I've been experimenting with the jQuery UI draggable/droppable interaction to allow a user to set ships for a game of Battleship. As far as I can tell, droppable interactions work just fine when the drop location is appropriately sized to fit a draggable item, but in the Battleship game, you have ships of several different lengths that fit into a number of squares ranging 2-5.

If you check out this jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/cDqGN/), and mess around with the ship of length two (versus the single block), you'll see it's fairly easy to screw up the drop, with the ship getting stuck between squares, or getting dragged a square to the right of where you intended to drop it.

Does anyone know of any tricks with this interaction to get it to go better?

In particular, this is the interaction as I have it now:

```
function handleDrop( event, ui ) {
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
}
```

Comment: Note: to reproduce the stuck-between-squares error, move the 2-ship directly up or down, without shifting its x-coordinate; in this way it will get stuck between squares. The 1-ship doesn't have this error though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using the `grid` option; I added the line below into your `handleDrop` function:

```
ui.draggable.draggable( "option", "grid", [ 52, 52 ] );
```

(It's 52x52 because the squares are 50x50, plus 1 on each side for the line width). After the ship is dragged to the board, you can then place the ship more precisely.

Here is the update jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cDqGN/1/

Comment: This looks beautiful in Safari and Firefox, but for whatever reason in Chrome it's misaligned--it won't let you enter the leftmost blocks and will let you place the piece off the right side of the board. I'll investigate further.

Comment: Hmm that's strange, it works for me in Chrome (at least through jsFiddle anyway); maybe it depends on the jQuery UI version?

Comment: Yes, this interaction works great with jQuery 1.9.1 & jQuery UI 1.9.2.